# How to evolutionary explain menstrural cycles synchronization?

Tags: human-biology, adaptation

Sorry, I can not indicate the source, but I read that menstrual cycles of women who live in the same house over time sync. Is it true? How does it work?

Comment: It is a myth which most likely came from methological flaws in the original study. It could never be reproduced. Read [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menstrual_synchrony) for details.

Comment: @Chris that's really interesting, I am aware of much anectodal evidence that suggests this is true. The wikipedia link you gave cites PMID:23480070 but I don't have access to it. Do you? Does it indeed confirm that it is a myth (the abstract suggests so but I don't know for sure)?

Comment: @terdon You can find the paper [here](http://www.directupload.net/file/d/3801/7pifeij3_pdf.htm), the part regarding the mentrual synchronisation starts on page 30 in the document. If you want to summarize the criticism in an answer, go for it.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the claimed fact is not supported by any reference. Suitable for Skeptics SE.

Comment: @ChrisStronks I guess you meant to ask Chris not me. There is nothing in my comment

Comment: Ok, made the comment into an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a myth which most likely came from methological flaws in the original study. It could never be reproduced. This paper ("[Darwin’s Legacy: An Evolutionary View of Women’s Reproductive and Sexual Functioning](http://www.directupload.net/file/d/3801/7pifeij3_pdf.htm)") deals with it. The interesting part starts from page 30 and says (the references can be ressolved in the article):

> **Critiques of MSH Studies**
>
> Wilson (1992) and Yang and Schank (2006),
>   among others, have criticized the study design, methods, and
>   statistics used by McClintock (1971) and others who have claimed
>   evidence of MS. For example, McClintock 
>   incorrectly used the Page test for ordered hypotheses with multiple
>   treatments (she used the same groups of women repeatedly instead of
>   independent treatments), making it impossible to evaluate the true
>   level of significance of her reported findings. Likewise, reports of
>   greater estrous synchrony in chimpanzees caged together than in those
>   caged apart (Wallis, 1985) and synchronization of estrogen peaks in a
>   sample of five golden lion tamarins (French & Stribley, 1987) are
>   rendered moot by the use of unsuitable statistical tests (Schank,
>   2001). Furthermore, computer simulations suggested that the null
>   hypothesis of no synchronization could not be rejected in either the
>   chimpanzee or tamarin samples (Schank, 2001).

Comment: Thanks for this enlightening answer Chris. It has been a long-standing myth that I believed for true.